# What is the difference between loop, comprehension and recursion in functional programming languages

Tags: loops, recursion, functional-programming, elixir

I'm studying elixir and I see that there is two ways to iterate

```
Comprehension
And recursion
```

I'd like to Know the difference between loop and comprehension specially,
I've googled the question but I'm not getting a satisfying answer.

Comment: What does this have to do with Haskell?

Comment: Looks like this question has been closed so I can’t answer it, but I can try to give at least an overview of an answer in the comments. (1/4)

Comment: __Recursion__ is when one function calls itself, stopping when a certain condition (the ‘base case’) has been reached. In purely functional programming languages, this is the basic construct for implementing iteration. (2/4)

Comment: A __loop__ is a construction where block of code is run multiple times until a condition is reached, often through updating the value of a variable while or until it meets the specified condition. In imperative programming languages, this is the basic construct for implementing iteration; by contrast, purely functional languages usually don’t provide loops. (A quick Google search tells me that Elixir doesn’t have any loops.) (3/4)

Comment: A __list comprehension__ is different to the other two constructions in that it cannot (usually) execute arbitrary code. Instead, a list comprehension can only be used to construct a list. A list comprehension goes through the elements of one (or more) list(s), sees which one(s) satisfy a certain condition, and gathers these satisfying elements into a new list. (4/4)

Comment: @bradrn thanks for answering in the comments 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> from [@bradrn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7345298/bradrn)

**Recursion** is when one function calls itself, stopping when a certain condition (the ‘base case’) has been reached. In purely functional programming languages, this is the basic construct for implementing iteration.

A **loop** is a construction where block of code is run multiple times until a condition is reached, often through updating the value of a variable while or until it meets the specified condition. In imperative programming languages, this is the basic construct for implementing iteration; by contrast, purely functional languages usually don’t provide loops. (A quick Google search tells me that Elixir doesn’t have any loops.)

A **list comprehension** is different to the other two constructions in that it cannot (usually) execute arbitrary code. Instead, a list comprehension can only be used to construct a list. A list comprehension goes through the elements of one (or more) list(s), sees which one(s) satisfy a certain condition, and gathers these satisfying elements into a new list.